# Example of 2 trinomial multiplication which is equal to sum of 2 monomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How to find out $P$ as an algebraic monomial which $P=ma$ and
$(a^2 P+1)(a^2 P+1)$ answer be sum of two monomials $Q,R$
eg $(a^2+a+1)(a^2-a+1) = a^4 + a^2 + 1$ which is sum of three monomials.
*Recently I found this problem on an advanced mathematics book based for 8th grade students so it is guaranteed there's a solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$x^4+4=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2).$$

Comment: An intermediate step may explain what is going on here: $x^4+4 = x^4 + 4 x^2 + 4 - 4 x^2 = (x^2 + 2)^2 - (2 x)^2 =(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2).$

Comment: thanx.
Is there any method or way to find out this solution?

Comment: @iman12: Andreas Caranti suggested something. But one can find it by fooling around. There is a closely related identity called the Sophie Germain identity. There is some theory for more general situations where the number of monomials shrinks, but it is not needed or useful for this example.